# How is active-active database architecture different from replica set based traditional architecture?

Tags: database, database-replication, database-administration, mongodb-replica-set, database-concurrency

I have read somewhere that active-active architecture facilitates concurrent write facility. Is it feasible? Basically I need to understand the core functionalities offered by this architecture which makes it a widely adopted paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

I did not heard about this in SQL Server regards. But if you are talking about other RDBMS then I am not aware of.
Thanks.